# Android Debug apk fully works but http calls don't work in signed release

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap

I have no idea where to look next on this issue so if someone can give me some pointers I'd be grateful:

I've built an app that has a http get call to a web api. This call returns specific data, formats it and dumps it into a div for displaying on the page. This all works lovely on the debug build, and updates in real time as data changes

However I've now built the signed release build of the app and this part no longer works. No data seems to get pulled and no divs get updated with info when you either start the app or refresh

I tried adding `android:debuggable=true` to the `manifest` but I'm not sure this is being applied when I rebuild the release (which I do through `cordova` as this is a `phonegap` app) and so try as I might I can't seem to get the app debugging at all. Having said that am I naive to assume that if the app works fully in the debug build then it should work fully in the release build?

This is my first full app

EDIT: I should have also mentioned that I have 2 separate HTTP calls. One of them was in a previous release build and worked perfectly, but now I've added a second that simply retrieves a second set of data from the same content they have both stopped working

Comment: Can you add error log while creating release build?

Comment: It's a problem with your server certificate. Debug apps ignore SSL errors, but release apps don't.

Comment: @R2R how would I do that?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I can see in the browser it warns that the SSL cert will be distrusted in M70 but it's just a warning. I can't see any other SSL errors being thrown currently. Also sorry but I also don't know how I'd correct an SSL cert  error in the release build :(

Comment: It's possible that even if Chrome trust it, the device doesn't. If it says that it's going to stop trusting it in M70 is for a reason. The only solution is to use a new trusted certificated on the server, there is nothing you can do on the app. Either that or use http for now until you get the certificate problem resolved

Comment: ok I'm struggling to see how this is a cert error. I have 3 calls, a https call to twitch API (which works and posts to channel chat as it should) and two http calls to get data from a http website. Call 1 works, grabs data, displays it and updates it fine but when I add the second data call to the same http site then both http calls fail to post data. the call to twitch still works

Answer (score 0):

So I rewrote most of the code, reordered some stuff and checked all code blocks were ended correctly. Then rebuilt a new release version and all calls are now working

No idea what was preventing the data from displaying but it all now fires and updates as it should

I've done nothing different in terms of certificate security, SSL or https so it doesn't seem like that was my issue. Thanks for the suggestions though